# Passing HTTP Auth Credentials to SOAP Webservice

Tags: silverlight, web-services, soap

I'm using a SOAP Webservice (ASMX) which is HTTP Auth secured in my Silverlight Application.
How can I pass my Credentials to the Webservice?

```
        bb_webservice = new BlackberryWSSoapClient();
        bb_webservice.GetLatestLocationsCompleted += new EventHandler<GetLatestLocationsCompletedEventArgs>(ws_proxy_GetLatestLocationsCompleted);
        bb_webservice.GetLatestLocationsAsync(0);
```

The credentials property isn't provided: 
http://dl.getdropbox.com/u/357576/ws.jpg

Any Help would be appreciated. Thanks.

rAyt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is "fixed" in Silverlight 3 Beta. Credentials property is there yet again.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the credentials property and pass a new [NetworkCredential](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkcredential.aspx) object:

```
bb_webservice = new BlackberryWSSoapClient();
bb_webservice.Credentials = 
       new System.Net.NetworkCredential("username","password","domain");
```

Comment: That's the strange thing. Crendentials isn't provided 
http://dl.getdropbox.com/u/357576/ws.jpg